# Difference between surface indices and ambient indices?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, tensors

Suppose there exists some arbitrary tensor $T^i_j$ where i and j are surface indices. The covariant surface derivative $\nabla_kT^i_j$ follows the normal covariant derivative expression $$\nabla_kT^i_j=\partial_kT^i_j+\Gamma^i_{km}T^m_j-\Gamma^m_{jk}T^i_m$$. However for the covariant surface derivative $\nabla_kT^i_j$ where i and j are now ambient indices we have a new expression that introduces the shift tensor $Z^r_k$ , thus the covariant surface derivative $\nabla_kT^i_j$ follows this new expression $$\nabla_kT^i_j=\partial_kT^i_j+Z_k^r\Gamma^i_{rm}T^m_j-Z^r_k\Gamma_{jr}^mT_m^i$$. Note that for the first expression with i and j as surface indices $\partial_k\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial S^k}$ and for the second expression where i and j are ambient indices $\partial_k\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial S_k}$ . My question is what is the difference between surface indices and ambient indices? Like what is the definition of surface indices and likewise for ambient indices?

Comment: where are you getting these notions from? I haven't heard the terms "surface indices" and "ambient indices" in particular, but I can guess that you have some $m$-dimensional Riemannian submanifold $M$ of some Riemannian $n$-manifold (most likely $\mathbb R^n$), where $m<n$. "Surface" makes me think that $m=2$. 
In this case you would have that the "surface indices" run over coordinates on $M$, so $i=1,\dots,m = 1,2$ while "ambient indices" will be in $\mathbb R^n$ coordinates, so $j = 1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Im getting these from the book "Introduction to tensor analysis and the calculus of moving surfaces"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us use an example of a 2D surface embedded in a 3D space and a vector field (an instance of a tensor field) defined on the embedded surface. In this scenario, the vector field often is assumed to lie in the tangent space of each point, so the component representation of the vector field requires two "surface components" that are denoted by "surface indices."

In that section of the book, however, the author investigates the case when the vector field also has a "surface normal component" outside of the tangent space. In this case, the component representation of the vector field needs to have three components, which are denoted by the "ambient indices."

If you are still unsure, it may be helpful to see the author's Youtube lecture video on this section: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8VGUooPINYg

I hope this information helps.